# Can't `go get` offline tutorial

Tags: linux, go

I am trying to run the command `go get golang.org/x/tour tour` but I am getting the error message `"package tour: unrecognized import path "tour" (import path does not begin with hostname)"`.  I also do not get the binary in my bin folder that is mentioned.

Things I have attempted to resolve the issue:

- Read the documentation at https://golang.org/doc/code.html and
  https://golang.org/doc/install.
- Verify workspace folders exist as specified in documentation (my
  workspace is `/home/USERNAME/go`, and inside that I have created 2
  folders `src` and `bin`).
- changed command from `go get golang.org/x/tour tour` to `go get
  golang.org/x/tour /home/USERNAME/go` (still get a simillar import path error message)
- verified that my go path is set correctly and go is installed using
  defaults, my go path in `/etc/profile` is `/usr/local/go/bin`
- since the command did create a directory called `golang.org`, I navigated to `/home/USERNAME/go/src/golang.org/x/tour` and ran `go build tour.go`.  I got the errors:

  ```
  # command-line-arguments
  ./tour.go:62:4: undefined: socketAddr
  ./tour.go:126:28: undefined: prepContent
  ```
- read the README.md in the golang.org/x/tour folder
- change bin permissions to 755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax of `go get` is (run `go help get` to see):

```
usage: go get [-d] [-f] [-t] [-u] [-v] [-fix] [-insecure] [build flags] [packages]
```

Everything you list at the end are all packages to get. So you should simply run:

```
go get golang.org/x/tour
```

Note: there is no need to pass an additional `tour` parameter. This is what the error message tells you: the `tour` package is not recognized.

The above command will get the `golang.org/x/tour` and install it into your `$GOPATH/bin`, so you can simply run it after the above command like:

```
$GOPATH/bin/tour
```

Answer (score 0):

After 
go get golang.org/x/tour

Run go build

This will generate executable which on run start local tour at http://127.0.0.1:3999/

Answer (score 0):

For me simply running the `tour`command worked fine , command-line output as follows !

```
C:\Users\ilife\go\src\golang.org\x\tour>tour
2020/05/23 20:04:39 Serving content from C:\Users\ilife\go\src\golang.org\x\tour
2020/05/23 20:04:39 A browser window should open. If not, please visit http://127.0.0.1:3999
2020/05/23 20:04:46 accepting connection from: 127.0.0.1:52660
```